# ShowWindow restores the window only if is the last minimized

Tags: c++, winapi, findwindow, showwindow

I'm trying to make a program in C++ that shows a minimized calculator.

It works if I minimize it, but if I minimize the Calculator and then another program like firefox, the program doesn't show the calculator anymore.

```
int main()
{
    hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,TEXT("Calculator"));
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check for errors. Both `FindWindow` and `ShowWindow` can fail. Read it up in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If the calculator is minimized (see [`IsIconic()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic)), then you should be using `SW_RESTORE` instead of `SW_SHOW`, per the [`ShowWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) documentation:

> SW_RESTORE
> 9
>
> Activates and displays the window. **If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.**
>
> SW_SHOW
> 5
>
> Activates the window and displays it **in its current size and position**.

Try this:

```c
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Calculator"));
    if (hwnd)
    {
        if (IsIconic(hwnd))
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
        else
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
    return 0;
}
```